# Developing for the windows slate

Tags: windows, api, xna, tablet

as Microsoft are releasing a tablet later this year, with a new operating system I was wondering whether we can already create apps for this platform and have them on the market place prior to release?

If this is the case where could I get my hands on the API's needed to go about creating a touch application in XNA for the upcoming windows 8 tablet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Right now it looks like XNA applications will not be directly supported by the marketplace [(source)](http://www.armlessoctopus.com/2012/03/09/microsoft-outlines-their-unified-metro-vision-sans-xna/); however, [MonoGame](http://monogame.codeplex.com/) games are able to get into the Marketplace.  This is an open-source alternative to XNA.

At this point, consider XNA to be around for a few more years but not directly supported in anything other than what it currently works on Xbox, Windows Phone, and Windows but not on the Windows 8 Marketplace.

Comment: Thanks, monogame looks interesting. Have you used it before? I'm interested in using this for porting to ios and windows devices. How does monotouch and monodevelop link with this project? As I've seen these mentioned in quite a few posts after googling monogame.

Comment: A little bit. It's pretty good. I have encountered a few things not complete here and there especially in 3D.  Monotouch you have to pay for and Monodevelop is just an open-source IDE.  Mono is the name of the alternative to .NET that is open source and runs on all platforms.

Comment: Just found out you need monotouch to push out to android and iPhone. As good as C# is I think the $600 price tag for both is too much. I'm guessing you can just use monogame and vs to push to windows devices though which is probably what ill do.

Comment: Yeah.  MonoTouch and Mono for Android is more for people who will be making enough money putting it on other platforms.